# How reference volume and environment variable with docker in Api net core

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, environment-variables, volumes

Actually in mi Apigateway with net core i have the next folder structure:

[image]

In Program.cs i need reference the file configuration like _pathConfigOcelot:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string _pathConfigOcelot = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OcelotConfigPath");
        CreateHostBuilder(args, _pathConfigOcelot).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args, string pathConfigOcelot) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .ConfigureAppConfiguration(
                      ic => ic.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(pathConfigOcelot,
                                                        "configuration.json")))
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => 
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

Actually i use **docker-compose** for use volumes:

```
services: 
  tresfilos.webapigateway:
  image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}tresfilosapigateway
  build: 
    context: .
    dockerfile: tresfilos.ApiGateway/ApiGw-Base/Dockerfile
  environment: 
   - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
   - IdentityUrl=http://identity-api
  ports:
   - "7000:80"
   - "7001:443"
  volumes:
   - ./tresfilos.ApiGateway/Web.Bff:/app/configuration
```

**I dont know how use docker volume like reference for configuration.js in the project, any idea ?**

Answer (score 0):

I read this `./tresfilos.ApiGateway/Web.Bff:/app/configuration` as `/app/configuration` is the alias of `./tresfilos.ApiGateway/Web.Bff` within my app.

So I'd say you reference the file as `/app/configuration/configuration.json`

Update:

Adding / after the Web.Bff might help.

Comment: Only for test i put directly in the code the docker path and have this error: "The configuration file './tresfilos.ApiGateway/Web.Bff\configuration.json' was not found and is not optional."................................. Then if i put in the code /app/configuration, this not produce an error in the container ??

Comment: BTW, I noticed that you're missing a `/` before the `:`.

Comment: I dont understand, is not because changes the \ / in the path ?  ./tresfilos.ApiGateway/Web.Bff\configuration.json

Comment: `./tresfilos.ApiGateway/Web.Bff/:/app/configuration` instead of `./tresfilos.ApiGateway/Web.Bff:/app/configuration` then reference the file as /app/configuration/configuration.json

Comment: I use Path.Combine then that method include "\" between. But first (for test) i´m trying to reference the physical path like:       
 Path.Combine("./tresfilos.ApiGateway/Web.Bff",
                                                            "configuration.json")

Comment: Yeah you might want to try and use string interpolation or concatenation and see if we're even in the right direction here.